# Rewrite in Nginx Does not work for POST request

Tags: domain-name-system, nginx, load-balancing, rewrite

I have two VPS(one is for fail over), both running Nginx as a Load balancer for  backend servers. Also, I have Enabled and configured SSL for my domain(registered on GoDaddy.com) on Nginx.

Since I am using DNS A records to configure the domain for VPS fail over  therefore I cannot enter port numbers(only IP number is allowed).So, by default the domain pings to port 80. But ssl listens on port 443.

For this I am using rewrite method in the server block of nginx but it doesn't work for the POST request. Although it works for a GET request .
I know that proxy_pass can be used with POST request but that is not the correct practice(Unsafe). I should be posting a request directly on HTTPS connection.

here is my nginx conf:

```
upstream tomcat_servers{
    least_conn;
    server 123.45.678.90:8080;
    server 124.345.78.23:8180;
    }

server {
   listen  80;
   server_name thedomain.com;
   rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
      }


 server {
   listen 443;
   server_name thedomain.com;

....ssl config.....


  location / {
         proxy_pass   http://tomcat_servers;                                                                                   
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_connect_timeout 30s;
         proxy_read_timeout 30s;
         proxy_send_timeout 30s;
         proxy_next_upstream timeout;
         proxy_next_upstream error invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_404 http_503 http_504;
  }
 }
```

How should I configure to make it work with POST requests in the given scenario.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should not use redirect for post. If you have to, you should use 307 code for post. A end-user may be prompted about redirection.

[W3C Specifications - RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

> **301 Moved Permanently**
>   If the 301 status code is received in response
>   to a request other than GET or HEAD, the user agent MUST NOT
>   automatically redirect the request unless it can be confirmed by the
>   user, since this might change the conditions under which the request
>   was issued.
>
> **Note: When automatically redirecting a POST request after**
>   **receiving a 301 status code, some existing HTTP/1.0 user agents**
>   **will erroneously change it into a GET request.**
>
> **307 Temporary Redirect** If the 307 status code is received in response
>   to a request other than GET or HEAD, the user agent MUST NOT
>   automatically redirect the request unless it can be confirmed by the
>   user, since this might change the conditions under which the request
>   was issued.

Look [also here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect)

Answer (score 1):

You should fix your application so that it uses only `https://domain.com/page` or `//domain.com/page` format URLs.

The redirection rule should be only used for a convenience for users so that they can make the first visit to the site by just typing the domain name.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @filmonic and Tero for correcting me, AS everyone suggested that redirection is not the best practice with POST request so I made  changes in the architecture of my server side network. And it works. My Architecture now looks somewhat like this

```
                         ________________
                        |                |
                        |     CLIENT     |
                        |  WEB BROWSER   |
                        |________________|
                                ||
                                || SSL
                         _______\/_______
                        |                |
                        |   DNS SERVER   |
                        |   (NEW YORK)   |
                        |________________|
                                ||
                                ||
                        _______/  \_______
                       /                  \
                      /  SSL               \ SSL
     ____________________                ____________________
    |                    |              |                    |
    |   SAN FRANCISCO    |              |     NEW YORK       |
    |____________________|              |____________________|
    |   ______________   |              |   ______________   | 
    |  |              |  |              |  |              |  |
    |  |     APP      |  |              |  |     APP      |  |
    |  | LOAD BALANCE |  |              |  | LOAD BALANCE |  |
    |  |     PROXY    |  |              |  |     PROXY    |  |
    |  |_____    _____|  |              |  |_____    _____|  |
    |________|  |________|              |________|  |________|
              ||      __                  __      ||
              ||<=====||==================||=====>||    
              \/      \/                  \/      \/
     ____________________                ____________________
    |                    |              |                    |
    |    SAN FRANCISCO   |              |      NEW YORK      |
    |____________________|              |____________________|
    |   ______________   |              |   ______________   |
    |  |              |  |              |  |              |  |
    |  |  APP SERVERS |  |              |  |  APP SERVERS |  |
    |  |______  ______|  |              |  |______  ______|  |
    |   ______||______   |              |   ______||______   |
    |  |              |  |              |  |              |  |
    |  |   DATABASE   |<==================>|   DATABASE   |  |
    |  |______________|  | MASTER-SLAVE |  |______________|  |
    |____________________|              |____________________|
```